# How to separately sort lines within multiple "chunks" separated with headers?

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

<sub>This question is complementary to this one: [*Sort packs of lines alphabetically*](https://superuser.com/q/1327747/432690). After answering there, it turned out I had totally misunderstood the question and solved another problem. Not wanting my solution to be forgotten, I'm posting the problem here (and my solution below).</sub>

---

Consider a text like:

```
[ProfileB]
param3=z
param2=y
param1=x
[ProfileA]
param1=k
param3=l
param2=
```

I need to sort parameters within every `[Profile*]` block separately. The above example should be sorted to this:

```
[ProfileB]
param1=x
param2=y
param3=z
[ProfileA]
param1=k
param2=
param3=l
```

How can I do it with standard Unix/Linux tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in my Debian:

```
sed '1 ! s/^\[/\x00\[/' |
split -t '\0' -l 1 --filter='
   tr -d "\0" |
   { IFS="" read -r REPLY; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort; }
'
```

To work with file(s) use redirection(s), e.g. `{ sed … ; } <input.txt >output.txt`, where `sed …` is the whole command.

The procedure is as follows:

1. `sed` inserts null character before every `[` that is in the beginning of a line, unless the line is the first one. This way null characters separate profiles.
2. `split` generates chunks, taking records separated by null characters, one record per chunk. Instead of writing to files, `split` calls a filter for each chunk separately:
3. at first `tr` deletes null characters (in practice: a single trailing null character in the chunk);
4. then `read` and `printf` just echo the first line (header) of the chunk;
5. at last `sort` does its job with remaining lines.
6. Chunks are processed sequentially; the output is a single concatenated stream.