# In bash, how can I replace empty lines with null and vice-versa?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed, sorting

How can I replace two newline characters `\n\n` with a null `\0` character in bash, and vice-versa?

I see that `td` can replace a single newline with null, but not two consecutive newline characters. I tried `sed`, but it doesn't seem possible. `sed` seems "line based" and doesn't like messing with newline characters.

My reason for wanting to do this is to be able sort a file that has records separated by empty lines using `sort -z`. For example, given a file

```
record b
foo bar

record a
zee bee
dee da
```

I want to pipe that file into a transform that replaces blank lines with null, then into `sort -z`, and then replace null with blank lines, and finally have it spit out

```
record a
zee bee
dee da

record b
foo bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

The title asks about your attempted solution; you described the real problem in the question body. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). This answer doesn't exactly "replace empty lines with null and vice-versa", so it doesn't solve the title. It injects null bytes in the right places, then removes them (because I think it's easier), this way it solves the body.

---

#### Solution

Let's adjust this other answer of mine: [*Sort packs of lines alphabetically*](https://superuser.com/a/1327935/432690). Your question is almost a duplicate of the one I answered.

There, each record starts with a header like `[ProfileX]`. In your case we can say an empty line is such header, but the very first record misses it. To use the linked solution we need to add the first header beforehand, and to remove the first header at the end.

```
sed -e '1 s/^/\n/' -e '1 ! s/^$/\x00/' | sort -z | tr -d '\0' | sed -e '1 d'
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                           add missing header
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                apply the other answer (adjusted)
#                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove excessive header
```

Without this modification the first record from the input would appear in the output without any empty line before it; this would be a problem, unless it's the first record in the output. And the first record in the output would have its header (if any) before it; this would be a problem unless it was the first record of the input (the one without a header).

Comment: Thanks! For me, `sed -e 's/^$/\x00` replaces empty lines with the character sequence "x00" instead of a null character. Do not all versions of `sed` understand that character escape sequence?

Comment: @ChristopherKing Not all versions. This answer, like the other one, was tested on Debian. I have GNU `sed` there.

Comment: I tested on OSX so I have BSD `sed` and apparently it doesn't support hex escape sequences.
https://riptutorial.com/sed/topic/9436/bsd-macos-sed-vs--gnu-sed-vs--the-posix-sed-specification So looks like my problem is that I can't even express a null character on OSX! I have a crazy solution that uses `base64` to encoding the record onto a single line prefixed with the plain text I'm sorting on. I guess I'll just have to go with that..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to struggle with 0 as a delimiter. Let's use 255 (hex FF) instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ORIGINAL=/path/to/yourfile.txt
SORTED=${ORIGINAL}.sorted
FF=$'\xff'

while read LINE ;do
  if [ "$LINE" = "" ] ;then
    echo
  else 
    echo -n $LINE$FF
  fi
done <$ORIGINAL | sort | tr $FF '\n' >$SORTED
```

Result:

```
record a
zee bee
dee da

record b
foo bar
```

Notice: The above assumes that your line endings are Linux (LF), not Windows (CR+LF) or Mac (CR).  If you want it to work with any kind of line endings, then we'll have to rework the script a little.