# Remove duplicate multiline patterns in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have this text file in which I would want to remove multi-line duplicates.

In this case, the `interface e0/0` block is repeated in the file, and I would like only a single instance of these lines within the file.

Would there be a utility in Linux or bash that I can use to do that?

**Sample text file**

```
interface e0/0
 description "R1"
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface e0/1
 description "R2"
 ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface e0/0
 description "R1"
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface e0/2
 description "R3"
 ip address 10.1.3.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
```

**After processing**

```
interface e0/0
 description "R1"
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface e0/1
 description "R2"
 ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface e0/2
 description "R3"
 ip address 10.1.3.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
```

Comment: May we assume a repeated `interface e0/0` line indicates a repeated block? Or should we verify if the two relevant blocks match each other in their entirety? What if they don't?

Comment: Yes i believe that would work since there should only be one instance of the pattern `interface e0/0` in the text though it would be better if the matching can be done for the whole code sub-block

Comment: "there should only be one instance of the pattern" – You mean: in the output? (if in the input then the whole question is pointless). So what should we do if there are two or more `interface e0/0` lines but the whole sub-blocks are different? Leave the first one? or the last one?

Comment: Is the order of multi-line sections important?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed response. as long as the output should only have one instance of the code block, the order doesn't matter, `interface e0/2` could come before `interface e0/1`

Comment: So which instance should we keep in case we meet two or more `interface e0/0` lines but the whole sub-blocks are different? The first one? or the last one? all of them?

Comment: only when the code blocks are exactly the same that it needs to have a single instance of it. If the sub-blocks are different, I don't want to do anything with it as I would need to review it first.

Comment: Something based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327935/432690) (but with `sort -uz`) would work, if only these `!` of yours were initiators or terminators, *not* separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
1 i \
!
s/^!/\x00!/' | sort -uz | tr -d "\0" | tail -n +2
```

To work with file(s) use redirection(s), e.g. `{ sed … ; } <input.txt >output.txt`, where `sed …` denotes the whole command.

The solution is based on [my another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327935/432690). It works like this:

1. `sed` prints `!` before the first line, so instead of your `!` being separators, we have `!` being initiators. In other words each block has its own `!` in front.
2. `sed` inserts a null character before every `!` that comes from the input (not from `sed`) and is in the beginning of a line. This way null characters separate profiles.
3. `sort -z` uses these null characters as separators, so it sorts whole profiles, not separate lines. Sorting is a side effect; we need it, so identical profiles end up next to each other and `-u` reduces them to one instance.
4. `tr` deletes null characters.
5. `tail` drops the first line which is `!` for sure. This way `!` are separators again.

Note:

- "Identical" in this answer really means identical. Different indentation, different order of lines or a trailing space is enough to make one block different than another.